# Looking for a 1969 paper by Tiao and Afonja

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request

In Wiley's "Continuous Multivariate Distributions, Volume 1: Models and Applications", Chapter 49 "Dirichlet and Inverted Dirichlet Distributions" the authors Kotz, Balakrishan and Johnson write

> Tiao and Afonja (1969) obtained some approximations to the probability integral $Pr[\bigcap_{i=1}^k (Y_i\leq a_i)]$

In their bibliography they cite

> Tiao, G. C., and Afonja, B. (1969) Some approximations and uses of the Dirichlet distributions, Preliminary Report, Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 40, 1514 (Abstract)

The Annals of mathematical statistics are fully available and open access, so I found the citation in question without too much effort here: https://www.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177697529

However, this is indeed only the abstract. I have yet to find any full paper, or any details on what the approximations look like. Wiley's book is also the only citing book or article I found. I could also only find one joint paper by Tiao and Afonja (1976) which is unrelated to the abstract.

Is there any way I could try to find the full article, if it was ever published?